# Regex to find a hard coded strings in aspx pages

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Looking for some RegEx advice. Working on trying to find hard coded strings in a C# .net app. All the properly coded strings in the aspx pages look like so:

`Text="<%$ Resources:Global, Delete %>"`
 I'm trying to find any string that would look like `Text="Delete"` or any hard coded strings. I've came up with `Text=\"(?!<%$ )?\"` to basically say find any string that does start out with `text="<%$"` but to no avail. Advice?

Answer (score 0):

"$" means something else for regex syntax (end of line). Escape it.

Moreover did you meant `Text=\"(?!\<%\$ )[^\"]*\"` ? this one works (tested).

Answer (score 0):

try the below expression

```
"(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)*"
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will return the hard-coded text, without results with a resource.

```
Text="(?<=\=\")[^><]+?(?=\")"
```